# What to do if you have a troubled relation with your postdoc supervisor?

Tags: advisor, postdocs, interpersonal-issues

It seems my relation with my postdoc supervisor has hit troubled waters after an amazing start. Things started to turn towards the worse since our first publication together, particularly after I took a parental leave. I'm not sure, if I could do my second paper, as my post-doctoral fellowship is coming to an end by the end of this month.

I'm worried about my career, as his reference would play a big role. Any ideas on how to deal with a bad reference?
(In the time remaining, I hope to fix our relation as much as possible...)

Comment: What do you mean by "a troubled relationship"? I don't think anyone can advise without at least some indication of the problem. Do you two argue a lot? Does the supervisor seem upset with the quality of your work? etc.

Comment: @ff524: It is a bit difficult to explain... When we made our first paper, he was interested in particular formatting, on which I had reservations. As I expected, the editor asked us to reformat the paper, which I did. Then was a major review, followed by minor one. During this entire episode, I was chastised for using Endnote...! Then when I applied for my parental leave, the lab rejected even when I had made it in well in advance. Then it went for review and they granted it after the date he approved. I tried to contact him before accepting it but he was on vacation and wouldn't respond.

Comment: @ff524: Then the lab asked me to contact his second in command, who agreed with the dates proposed by the lab. When my supervisor returned he had been chastising and belittling that I had taken the leave without his permission. Then came the work for our second paper. He made me process data (>TBs), only to find that the data was crap, and I have been blamed for time spent on processing that data. Again, I was asked to download data (TBs) and I wrote program to unzip them automatically. When the disk ran out of space, I'm chastised for that too...It seems he is blaming me for each&everything

Comment: I voted to reopen, but you might have better luck starting fresh (if that's allowed -- if in doubt, ask on Meta).  I would focus on the reference aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments it sounds like a Setup-to-fail syndrome. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setting_up_to_fail

The Wiki article is a bit iffy, but it basically means that he somewhat has low expectations of your performance after some incident. Thereby, when something happens he assumes is your fault because he has low expectations nevertheless.

Is usually a toxic relationship because is self fulfilling (you'll end up making mistakes, because he wants to) and self reinforcing (the mistake you just did helps him reinforce the idea that you'll make more).

Is a vicious circle that has to be addressed by both you and your boss (PI, manager, etc). But is usually a good idea to have some other people on your side.

Ultimately, if he is unwilling to change, it is better for you to leave for a less toxic environment.

Comment: I'm leaving and there is no time to fix the relationship, anyway. I worried about my future, as he could literally give a bad reference and screw me up badly...!

Comment: @Samuel If you're asking about how to avoid a bad reference, you should edit your post to say so. Right now it sounds like you're asking how to fix the relationship.

Comment: @ff524: Thanks... I modified my question... hope it is clear now..!

Comment: Even if you are leaving, I commend you to try and fix as much as you can the relationship. If even as a sign of good faith before you leave.